# Uploading multiple files using formData()

Tags: javascript, arrays, upload, xmlhttprequest

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("fileToUpload", document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0]);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "uph.php");
xhr.send(fd);
```

uph.php:

```
var_dump($_FILES['fileToUpload']);
```

This works, but obviously for the `files[0]` only. How to get this working for chosen file?

I tried removing the `[0]`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 146):

You have to use `files.length` to append in JavaScript, and then send it via an Ajax request:

**JavaScript:**

```
var files = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files;
for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
    fd.append("fileToUpload[]", files[x]);
}
```

**PHP:**

```
$count = count($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    echo 'Name: '.$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'][$i].'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. I guess it depends on how your multipart form will handled server sided.

Comment: [According to MDN `As with regular form data, you can append multiple values with the same name. For example (and being compatible with PHP's naming conventions by adding [] to the name):`. See Example 3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) @Phoenix

Comment: only returns one file

Comment: `fileToUpload[]` is wrong, should be `fileToUpload`

Comment: @HoussemBadri in my case `fileToUpload` doesn't work. it should be `fileToUpload[]` as suggested in the answer. Your comment cost me an hour to find out what's going on.

Comment: @UXAndre sorry for that but, I commented based on my real case

Comment: in my case fileToUpload  worked , Anyways you saved me

Answer (score 104):

The way to go with javascript:

```
var data = new FormData();

$.each($("input[type='file']")[0].files, function(i, file) {
    data.append('file', file);
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/your/url',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data : data,
    success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
})
```

If you call data.append('file', file) multiple times your request will contain an array of your files.

[From MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append):

> "The `append()` method of the `FormData` interface appends a new value onto an existing key inside a `FormData` object, or adds the key if it does not already exist.
> The difference between `FormData.se`t and `append()` is that if the specified key already exists, `FormData.set` will **overwrite** all existing values with the new one, whereas `append()` will append the new value onto the end of the existing set of values."

Myself using node.js and multipart handler middleware multer get the data as follows:

```
router.post('/trip/save', upload.array('file', 10), function(req, res){
    // Your array of files is in req.files
}
```

Comment: `...If you call data.append('file', file) multiple times your request will contain an array of your files...` Saved me hours of despair, especially because I felt the name should be `file[]`, but using just `file` and calling multiple times worked, thanks!

Comment: Dude you are a legend have been searching for this from morning thanks allot man

Comment: I tried you example, but when I var_dumped it, it always return the last image of the set. I changed: `data.append('file', file)` to `data.append('file', i)`, that worked for me.

Comment: This line is the most important bit of information `If you call data.append('file', file) multiple times your request will contain an array of your files.`
Thanks a lot. Saved me hours of my time.

Comment: Setting the `FormData` to use the key `files` is what worked for me rather than making it appear as an array such as `files[]`

Comment: For folks using django who're looking to send such a request to your views. You might want to use `file_field` instead of `file` for consistency with where django's native forms put file data.
eg. `data.append('file_field', file)`, so in your view you'd continue to use `request.FILES.getlist('file_field')` like before.

Comment: not working for me. had to do data.append('file[]', file);

Comment: Great answer but would be better in vanilla js

Comment: How would you process the files on the back-end if you don't know the number of files you are receiving? In my opinion, I think you should send files as an array.

Answer (score 28):

You just have to use `fileToUpload[]` instead of `fileToUpload` :

```
fd.append("fileToUpload[]", document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[0]);
```

And it will return an array with multiple names, sizes, etc...

Comment: This needs to be loop, and append each `files[i]`

Answer (score 27):

This worked for me:

```
let formData = new FormData()
formData.append('files', file1)
formData.append('files', file2)
```

Comment: files must be append in loop.

Answer (score 11):

This one worked for me

```js
//Javascript part
//file_input is a file input id
var formData = new FormData();
var filesLength=document.getElementById('file_input').files.length;
for(var i=0;i<filesLength;i++){
 formData.append("file[]", document.getElementById('file_input').files[i]);
}
$.ajax({
   url: 'upload.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: formData,
   contentType: false,
   cache: false,
   processData: false,
   success: function (html) {
   
  }
});
```

```html
<?php
//PHP part
$file_names = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($file_names); $i++) {
   $file_name=$file_names[$i];
   $extension = end(explode(".", $file_name));
   $original_file_name = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
   $file_url = $original_file_name . "-" . date("YmdHis") . "." . $extension;
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$i], $absolute_destination . $file_url);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Adding `[]` when appending to fd works, but if you prefer to have your data grouped by file then I'd suggest doing it this way:

```
var files= document.getElementById('inpFile').files
var fd = new FormData()

for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  fd.append(i, files[i])
}
```

Now your data will be sent grouped by file instead of grouped by attribute.

Answer (score 6):

I worked that such as:

```
var images = document.getElementById('fileupload').files;
var formData = new FormData();
for(i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
     formData.append('files', images[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked fine !

```
var fd = new FormData();

$('input[type="file"]').on('change', function (e) {
    [].forEach.call(this.files, function (file) {
        fd.append('filename[]', file);
    });
});

$.ajax({
    url: '/url/to/post/on',
    method: 'post',
    data: fd,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response)
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: Adding a short explanation to your code will make for a better answer! just a helpful tip

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

```js
var ins = $('.file').map(function () {
    return this.files;
}).get();

for (var x = 0; x < ins; x++) {
    formData.append("file", ins[x][0]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are instantiating the FormData object already passing the form as a constructor parameter, the input file's name attribute must contain the square brackets.

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST" action="url" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="file" name="photos[]" multiple />
```

JS:

```
var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('myForm'));
console.log(formData.getAll('photos[]'));
```

That worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me  also:

```
var data  = new FormData();
for (const key in files)
    data.append('gallery[]',files[key])
```

Answer (score 3):

If we have input in our html:

```
<input id="my-input" type="file" mutliple /> // multiple attribute to select and upload multiple files
```

We can get files from that input and send it to server with pure js script:

```
const myInput = document.getElementById('my-input') // getting our input

myInput.addEventListener('change', (event) => { // listening for file uploads
    const files = event.target.files // getting our files after upload
    const formData = new FormData() // create formData

    for (const file of files) {
        formData.append('files', file) // appending every file to formdata
    }

    const URL = 'http://api.server.com'
    const response = fetch(URL, {
       method: 'POST',
       data: formData // sending our formdata in body of post request
    })

    return response.json() 
}
```

It worked perfect for me

P.S.: I used `multer` in backend (node.js + express), added to file upload route

```
upload.array("files", 10)
```

- First argument is a property name of our files (in formdata)
- Second argument is max file size

Comment: Domains do not use ports (`:3000`), that only works for local servers.

Comment: Yes of course, if you are uploading image in frontend, you get image and send it to backend server with host:port

Comment: Yes, local servers not domains.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the **Vanilla JavaScript** solution for this issue -

First, we'll use `Array.prototype.forEach()` method, as

`document.querySelectorAll('input[type=file]')` returns an **array like object**.

Then we'll use the `Function.prototype.call()` method to assign each element in the **array-like object** to the `this` value in the `.forEach` method.

**HTML**

```
<form id="myForm">

    <input type="file" name="myFile" id="myFile_1">
    <input type="file" name="myFile" id="myFile_2">
    <input type="file" name="myFile" id="myFile_3">

    <button type="button" onclick="saveData()">Save</button>

</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 function saveData(){
     var data = new FormData(document.getElementById("myForm"));
     var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=file]');

     Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs[0].files, function(index){
        data.append('files', index);
     });
     console.log(data.getAll("myFile"));
}
```

**You can view the working example of the same [HERE](https://codepen.io/bappidas/pen/BaabxrX)**

Comment: yeah, looking for the vanila JavaScript solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To upload multiple files with angular form data, make sure you have this in your component.html

**Upload Documents**

```
                <div class="row">


                  <div class="col-md-4">
                     &nbsp; <small class="text-center">  Driver  Photo</small>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input  (change)="onFileSelected($event, 'profilepic')"  type="file" class="form-control" >
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-4">
                     &nbsp; <small> Driver ID</small>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input  (change)="onFileSelected($event, 'id')"  type="file" class="form-control" >
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    &nbsp; <small>Driving Permit</small>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="file"  (change)="onFileSelected($event, 'drivingpermit')" class="form-control"  />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>



                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                       &nbsp; <small>Car Registration</small>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group mb-4">
                            <input class="form-control" 
                (change)="onFileSelected($event, 'carregistration')" type="file"> <br>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <small id="li"> Car Insurance</small>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group mb-4">
                          <input class="form-control" (change)="onFileSelected($event, 

                         'insurancedocs')"   type="file">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>


                <div style="align-items:c" class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data- 
                  dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary"  (click)="uploadFiles()">Upload 
                  Files</button>
                  </div>
              </form>
```

In your componenet.ts file
declare array selected files like this

```
selectedFiles = [];
```

// array of selected files

```
onFileSelected(event, type) {
    this.selectedFiles.push({ type, file: event.target.files[0] });
  }
```

//in the upload files method, append your form data like this

```
uploadFiles() {
    const formData = new FormData(); 

    this.selectedFiles.forEach(file => {
      formData.append(file.type, file.file, file.file.name); 
    });
    formData.append("driverid", this.driverid);

    this.driverService.uploadDriverDetails(formData).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res); 

      },
      error => console.log(error.message)
    );
  }
```

NOTE: I hope this solution works for you friends

Answer (score 1):

```
let fd = new FormData();
fd.append( "images" , image1 );
fd.append( "images" , image2 );
fd.append( "images" , image3 );
```

In this format you can send multiple file by axios.
But i had some problem with this.
only one file was uploaded when i try to append in form data and try to send this through axios.
and my problem was that i had imported {Axios} from 'axios'
but it will not gonna work.
we have to import axios from 'axios'
( look at the spelling )
then it was work perfectly for me

Answer (score 0):

Create a `FormData` object

```
const formData: any = new FormData();
```

And append to the same keyName

```
photos.forEach((_photoInfo: { localUri: string, file: File }) => {
    formData.append("file", _photoInfo.file);
});
```

and send it to server

```
// angular code
this.http.post(url, formData)
```

this will automatically create an array of object under `file`

if you are using nodejs

```
const files :File[] = req.files ? req.files.file : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this work for me!

```
var fd = new FormData();
$.each($('.modal-banner [type=file]'), function(index, file) {
  fd.append('item[]', $('input[type=file]')[index].files[0]);
});

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'your/path/', 
  data: fd,
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  cache: false,
  success: function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
}).done(function() {
  // do something....
});
return false;
```

Comment: please add more explanation to your answer

Answer (score 0):

Appending multiple files to the same key didn't work for me. I ended up appending them separately.

```
files.forEach((file) => {
    formData.append(`file-${file.name}`, file);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  var fd = new FormData();
    //assuming file inputs have a common classname (always   easier when they do)
    var fileInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.fileToUpload');
    var fileInputsArray = Array.from(fileInputs);
    
    //"upload" is the parameter you may chose to store the files 
    fileInputsArray.forEach((element, index) => {
       fd.append(`upload[${index}]`, element.files[0])
    });

    //do your ajax here
    //you could use fetch as well
    fetch(`${origin}`/api_uri,{
      method: "POST",
      body: fd,
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json"
      },
    })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In React & Typescript app use the same key for each file, server will treat it as array:

```
const formData = new FormData();

    if (state.files && state.files.length > 0) {
      state.files.forEach((file: File) => {
        // Use the same key 'files' for each file
        formData.append('files', file);  
      });
    }
```