# Javascript Add multiple file inputs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file, input

I have a form and file input. I want to select images from another folder.

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_FILES);
echo '</pre>';
```

When I send my form I need to see all selected images but I see only the last selected.

For example, the first time I select 2 files. After selecting 5 files and submitting  my form I see only the last selected files, but I need to send all 7 files. Is it possible??

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="sell-images" name="images[]" multiple>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I have this function for file counter:

```
    $.fn.fileUploader = function (filesToUpload, sectionIdentifier) {
    var fileIdCounter = 0;

    this.closest("#sell-images").change(function (evt) {
        var output = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < evt.target.files.length; i++) {
            fileIdCounter++;
            var file = evt.target.files[i];
            var fileId = sectionIdentifier + fileIdCounter;

            filesToUpload.push({
                id: fileId,
                file: file
            });
        };

        for(var z = 0; z < filesToUpload.length; z++)
        {
            evt.target.files[z] = filesToUpload[z]['file'];
        }
        console.log(evt.target.files)
    });

    return this;
};
```

Here is my onchange function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var filesToUpload = [];
  var files1Uploader = $("#sell-images").fileUploader(filesToUpload, "images[]");

  $("#sell-images").on('change',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

Here I see in console all selected files from another folder

```
    console.log($("#sell-images")[0].files);

    var formData = new FormData();

    for (var i = 0, len = filesToUpload.length; i < len; i++) {
      formData.append("files", filesToUpload[i].file);
    }
  });
});
```

Here I have all selected files, but when I want to select a new file and send post in my PHP file, the global variable `$_FILES` shows me only the last selected files.

How can I send my all selected files?

I can do it with another technique every time when selecting a file with JavaScript hide that input and create new but I don't want that.

Comment: code formatting, grammar and question clarity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading multiple files using formData()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989442/uploading-multiple-files-using-formdata)

Comment: I'm not sure of your exact HTML layout and I don't how many items with the same `sell-images` ID you have but, in general terms, you cannot normally push stuff into file upload controls. I believe old Opera browser would allow it (after showing a prompt) but it isn't something you can rely on.

Answer (score 0):

> *..., but I need to send all 7 files. Is it possible??*

Yes it is possible.

> *How can I send my all selected files?*

Use [the array syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) for multiple files. With the current implementation, the last file overwrites all previous entries in the formData object. So update this line:

```
formData.append("files", filesToUpload[i].file);
```

To this:

```
formData.append("files[]", filesToUpload[i].file);
```

That way all the files in the array `filesToUpload` will be sent, instead of just the last one.

See this demonstrated in [this plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/qlyeYqjdaotA84eOPH4S/).

Comment: In your example when i send post with my form in $_FILES show 1 array me need show all but i read about it and i think what i want do now impossible

Comment: What do you want to do?