# Why is it safe to send Array of File Objects via Ajax but not via a regular Http Request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, multipartform-data, form-data

I use an HTML form to allow the user to upload files.

In order to make adding attachments more user friendly, I added client side code to allow the user to add/remove files (I basically did this as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43349767/how-to-add-upload-choose-multiple-files-from-one-input-tag/43350093#comment86126810_43350093#answer-43350093)).

Because I don't want to adjust too much of my server side code, I'd still like to send the form in a regular request, handle it on my server, and return an Http Response (ie: no Ajax, send request from same thread as main page and then redirect or forward the response on my `Servlet`).

However, the only way to submit the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) Object is via Ajax.
When I look for ways to send the `FormData` Object via a regular Http Request (eg: by attaching it to the form), I hear that this is not allowed because it is not safe.

Why can the `FormData` be submitted via `XMLHttpRequest` but submitting via regular Http Request (like a regular form submit) is considered not safe to the user? What's the difference?
To phrase this another way: You can mess with attachments if you're submitting them via `Ajax` but not via a regular request. Why?

If there is a way to submit the `FormData` in a regular request, I would be interested to hear what it is.

Thanks.

**Extra clarification (motivated by comments):**

The input element on the form does not accurately represent the user's selections. I allow the user to add/remove files. I do this by creating my own `Array` of `File` Objects in the client side code. This new array of `File` Objects needs to be sent with the request. This is possible with Ajax (ie: by creating a `FormData` Object), not with regular form submit; why?

Comment: `FormData` is used to create an object based on a `<form>` which can then be sent via AJAX. If you want to send files the non-Ajax way, just don't create a FormData object in the first place. All you have to do is add `<input>`s to your form. Not sure where the issue is, tbh.

Comment: I am creating my own Array of `File` Objects. Please read second paragraph (including link).

Comment: I'm aware of what you're trying to do; my suggestion is to use the array method, then to build `<input>`s based on them and add them to a `<form>`, instead of building a FormData object and sending it via AJAX.

Comment: Adding `<input>` elements is no problem, but how do I set the `File` Object to them? From what I understand, this is not possible... To recap again, I have an `Array` of `File` Objects. I can certainly use javascript to add an `<input>` element to my form for each one of these `File`s, but I cannot set its [value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Comment: So get creative: let the user select a file, move the hidden `<input>` (which has its value set) inside the `<form>`, then create a new hidden one. https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/bke2nat3/ (btw, your comment that says "cannot set its value" clarifies your issue MUCH better than your edit)

Comment: That sounds doable I think. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisG Do you have any ideas for how to do this with a "multiple" input and also have the "remove" option? Slightly different from your jsfiddle, I print the file names to the page and allow the user to remove them. If they've uploaded (eg) 3 files at once, and then click "remove" on one of them, I can't remove only one from the element.

Comment: I didn't want to spend an hour on this, essentially doing your work for you. Anyway, I don't think you can use `multiple` for this. And removing works by changing the existing mechanism so it looks for the corresponding `<input>` inside the form and removes it.

Answer (score 2):

> The only way to submit the FormData Object is via Ajax

This is not true.

A `FormData` object is simply a way of encoding binary data before transfer (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) for a full outline of its purpose). It is only really required when sending files (ie. binary data) to the server.

If you want to do that without AJAX, add the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to your `form` element and submit it as usual.

Also note that the use of `FormData` has nothing to do with security, as your question title implies.

Comment: How do I attach the `FormData` object to the form? I created the `FormData` Object in the client side code. The `form` doesn't know about it yet.

Comment: You don't need to. You only need to build the `FormData` manually for an AJAX request. If you don't want (or need) to use AJAX, then just add the `enctype` attribute I mentioned above to the `<form>` and the browser will encode the data for you before submission.

Comment: Please read the second paragraph of the question (including the link). The `input` element on the `form` does not accurately represent the user's selections. I allow the user to add/remove files. I do this by creating my own `Array` of `File` Objects in the client side code. This new array of `File` Objects needs to be sent with the request. This is possible with Ajax, not with regular form submit; why?