# Upload multiple image using ajax and jquery in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am uploading multiple image using Ajax and Jquery. While passing image from view to controller in request i am getting all images in form of array now only single image is uploading.And to preview all image only single image is previewing.I want to upload all image and to preview all images.

Route:

```
Route::match(['post','get'],'/webadmin/uploadbanner','Webadmin\Banners@upload_banner_image');
```

Controller:

```
public function upload_banner_image(Request $request){
      if ($request->isMethod('get'))
          return view('/webadmin/uploadbanner');
      else {
          $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
              [
                  'file' => 'image',
              ],
              [
                  'file.image' => 'The file must be an image (jpeg, png, bmp, gif, or svg)'
              ]);
          if ($validator->fails())
              return array(
                  'fail' => true,
                  'errors' => $validator->errors()
              );
              $files = $request->file('files');
             $total = $request->TotalImages;
             foreach($files as $file) {
                  for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
                    $dir = 'public/assets/uploads/Banners/';
                    $imagename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                    $filename = uniqid() . '_' . time() . '.' . $imagename;
                    $file->move($dir, $filename);
                    return $filename;
                  }

       }

      }

   }
```

View :

```
<div class="form-group">
                                <label for="field-ta" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Featured Image</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="full editp">
                        <label for="name" ></label>
                        <div id="image">

                             <img width="100%" height="100%" id="preview_image" src="https://projects.caresortsolutions.com/Elearn/public/assets/Webadmin/images/attach-1.png"/>
                       <i id="loading" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw" style="position: absolute;left: 40%;top: 40%;display: none"></i>
                        </div>
                        <p>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                            <a href="javascript:upload_banner()" style="text-decoration: none;" class="btn btn-success">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit "></i> upload image
                            </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <a href="javascript:removeFile()" style="color: white;text-decoration: none;" class="btn btn-red">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash "></i>
                                Remove
                            </a>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </p>
                        <input type="file" id="file" style="display: none" multiple/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="file_name[]" id="file_name" />
                        </div> </div>
                            </div>
```

Ajax :

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
    function upload_banner(){
        j('#file').click();
    }
     j('#file').change(function () {
         if (j(this).val() != '') {
            upload(this);
      }
    });
    function upload(img) {
        let image_upload = new FormData();
        image_upload.append('_token', '{{csrf_token()}}');
        j('#loading').css('display', 'block');
        let TotalImages = j('#file')[0].files.length; 
         let images = j('#file')[0]; 
         for (let i = 0; i < TotalImages; i++) {
            image_upload.append('files[]', images.files[i]);
        }
        image_upload.append('TotalImages', TotalImages);
        j.ajax({
            url: "{{url('/webadmin/uploadbanner')}}",
            data: image_upload,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                if (data.fail) {
                  j('#preview_image').attr('src', '{{URL::to('/public/assets/Webadmin/images/attach-1.png')}}');
                    alert(data.errors['file']);
                }
                else {
                    j('#file_name').val(data);
                    j('#preview_image').attr('src', '{{URL::to('/public/assets/uploads/Banners/')}}/' + data);
                }
                j('#loading').css('display', 'none');
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                j('#preview_image').attr('src', '{{URL::to('/public/assets/Webadmin/images/attach-1.png')}}');

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting only last selected image?

Comment: i want to upload all images

Comment: `image_upload.append('files[]', images.files[i]);` is replacing the previous files and retain the last one and you must be getting only last. Is that correct ?

Comment: try `image_upload.append('files', images.files[i]);` just get rid of `[]` array

Comment: i have tried this but its not working for me it avoids uploading image and return url with no image with in image tag.

Comment: check this thread out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989442/uploading-multiple-files-using-formdata

Comment: Not sure of server side though, but you may debug from browser console if files being posted by jQuery

Comment: i am getting all images with in array while debugging using dd($request->all()); but unabling to upload all images .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your controller look like that

> first u upload all the images and then get image file name with path

```
public function upload_banner_image(Request $request){
      if ($request->isMethod('get'))
          return view('/webadmin/uploadbanner');
      else {
          $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
              [
                  'file' => 'image',
              ],
              [
                  'file.image' => 'The file must be an image (jpeg, png, bmp, gif, or svg)'
              ]);
          if ($validator->fails())
              return array(
                  'fail' => true,
                  'errors' => $validator->errors()
              );
             $files = [];  //store filename in this array.
            // $total = $request->TotalImages;  no need to check total images.
           if($request->files) {
             foreach($request->file('files') as $file) {
                    $dir = 'public/assets/uploads/Banners/';
                    $imagename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                    $filename = uniqid() . '_' . time() . '.' . $imagename;
                    $file->move($dir, $filename);
                    $files[] = $dir.$filename;
            } //foreach
         } //if
                 //return all the filename with path ...
           return response()->json(['files' => $files]);
     } //else
 } //function
```

your js code look like that

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
    function upload_banner(){
        j('#file').click();
    }
     j('#file').change(function () {
         if (j(this).val() != '') {
            upload(this);
      }
    });
    function upload(img) {
        let image_upload = new FormData();
        image_upload.append('_token', '{{csrf_token()}}');
        j('#loading').css('display', 'block');
        let TotalImages = j('#file')[0].files.length; 
         let images = j('#file')[0]; 
         for (let i = 0; i < TotalImages; i++) {
            image_upload.append('files[]', images.files[i]);
        }
        image_upload.append('TotalImages', TotalImages);
        j.ajax({
            url: "{{url('/webadmin/uploadbanner')}}",
            data: image_upload,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                if (data.fail) {
                  j('#preview_image').attr('src', '{{URL::to('/public/assets/Webadmin/images/attach-1.png')}}');
                    alert(data.errors['file']);
                }
                else {
                    if(data.files) {
                      data.files.forEach(function(item,key) {
                       //j('#file_name').val(item); //file with path
                          j('#preview_image').attr('src',item); //file with path
                       });    
                    } //if files get
                } //else
                j('#loading').css('display', 'none');
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                j('#preview_image').attr('src', '{{URL::to('/public/assets/Webadmin/images/attach-1.png')}}');

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: its giving call to undefined member function getClientOriginalName on array() and iam using   image_upload.append('files[]', images.files[i]); in ajax call

Comment: uploading works with changing foreach($request->file('files') as $file) {}

Comment: preview not getting all images but upload working proper.

Comment: @PriyaNegi u need to create `<ul>` html element add one by one image using `<li>`

Comment: @PriyaNegi great