# Send mutiple form data via javascript (or jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have these forms:

```
var formData = new FormData($('#form')[0]);
var formTRData = new FormData($('#form_tr')[0]);
var formTLData = new FormData($('#form_tl')[0]);
var formBRData = new FormData($('#form_br')[0]);
var formBLData = new FormData($('#form_bl')[0]);
```

And I send:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'aaaaa.php',
type: 'POST',
data: ????
```

How I can send all forms in data?

Comment: `data: [formData, formTRData, formTLData, formBRData, formBLData]`, then make sure `aaaaa.php` can handle data in that format.

Comment: When I received the data in php and I do var_dump($_POST) is empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading multiple files using formData()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989442/uploading-multiple-files-using-formdata)

Comment: @kemicofa, in this post the user add keys to the form, I need to send multiple forms

Answer (score 0):

You pass the data alomng like this
**data: {name: 'Wayne', age: 27, country: 'Ireland'},**
As you can see first comes the identifier of the parameter then a colon and the the actual data.

In your aaaaa,php then you can access the parameters via

```
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];
```

This should help

Comment: Thanks, but the forms are dinamycs and I doesn't know the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object containing all of these like this:

```
var data = {
    "formData": new FormData($('#form')[0]);
    "formTRData": new FormData($('#form_tr')[0]);
    "formTLData": new FormData($('#form_tl')[0]);
    "formBRData": new FormData($('#form_br')[0]);
    "formBLData": new FormData($('#form_bl')[0]);
}
```

Make sure your server-side is prepared to receive a complex object and parse it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the objects using $.param():

```
var postData = $.param(formData) + '&' + $.param(formTRData) + '&' + $.param(formTRData) + '&' + $.param(formTLData) + '&' + $.param(formBRData) + '&' + $.param(formBLData);

$.ajax({
url: 'aaaaa.php',
type: 'POST',
data: postData
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var formData = new FormData($('#form')[0]);
var formTRData = new FormData($('#form_tr')[0]);
var formTLData = new FormData($('#form_tl')[0]);
var formBRData = new FormData($('#form_br')[0]);
var formBLData = new FormData($('#form_bl')[0]); 
  
var formDataEntries = formData.entries();
var formTRDataEntries = formTRData.entries();
var formTLDataEntries = formTLData.entries();
var formBRDataEntries = formBRData.entries();
var formBLDataEntries = formBLData.entries();

var data = [...formDataEntries, ...formTRDataEntries, ...formTLDataEntries, ...formBRDataEntries, ...formBLDataEntries];
```

You can use spread operator for formData iterator.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

```
            var formData = new FormData($('#form')[0]);

        $.each($('#form_tr')[0], function(i, e) {
          formData.append(e.name, e.value);
        });
        $.each($('#form_tl')[0], function(i, e) {
          formData.append(e.name, e.value);
        });
        $.each($('#form_br')[0], function(i, e) {
          formData.append(e.name, e.value);
        });
        $.each($('#form_bl')[0], function(i, e) {
          formData.append(e.name, e.value);
        });
```