# Passing formdata to multer, not being parsed properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a POST request, that I'm sending from my frontend, with axios, where I send a `FormData` object, with an array of files, and some additional parameters

```
   const files = this.state.fileObjects
    const fields = {
        "name": this.state.name,
        "email": this.state.email,
        "message": this.state.message
    }

    const data = new FormData()
    //implement multer on server side
    for (const [index, file] of files.entries()) {
        data.append(`files[${index}]`, file)
    }
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(fields)){
        data.append(key, value)
        console.log(data)
```

I then use a post request, to send the data to my backend, where i let `multer` handle the `FormData` object

```
 axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/api/form',
        data: data,
        config: { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }}
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            //handle success
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (response) {
            //handle error
            console.log(response)
    })
```

when everything is appended to the formdata, object nothing is received properly on the backend. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try just writing `data.append('file[]', file)` and see if that helps

Comment: `file`, or `files`.. I have an array of files?

Comment: Yes, [but you can append multiple files with the `[]` notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989442/uploading-multiple-files-using-formdata)

Comment: I tried looping through the files, and adding them, but there was no output 
```files.forEach(file =>{
        data.append('files[]', file)
       })
       console.log(data.getAll("files")) //logs empty array```

Comment: Try and send it with `axios.post('/api/form', data)` and see if you get something on the server.

Comment: I tried it.. but nothing is received on the server side...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188874/discussion-between-baileyhaldwin-and-tholle).