# how to post multiple images from multiple fields in jquery ajax to laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, multipartform-data

i have multiple image fields so i want to know that how to append that multiple fields images in formdata and send through ajax

image fields

```
<div class="col-md-3 offset-1">
<input class="form-control" type="file" name="image">
<label class="control-label">Image</label><i class="bar"></i>
 </div>
<div class="col-md-3 offset-1">
 <input class="form-control" type="file" name="image" class="tei">
 <label class="control-label">Image</label><i class="bar"></i>
  </div>
<div class="col-md-3 offset-1">
 <input class="form-control" type="file" name="image" class="twi">
<label class="control-label">Image</label><i class="bar"></i>
 </div>
```

jquery code

```
var formdata=new FormData();



formdata.append('image',$('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
```

js error

```
VM1646 student-entry:606 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (VM1646 student-entry:606)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading multiple files using formData()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989442/uploading-multiple-files-using-formdata)

Comment: Just simple add `[]` in `name` attr like this : `<input class="form-control" type="file" name="image[]" class="twi">`

Comment: but all the fields are different i can't save the files at one folder