# How to post multiple files with fetch API?

Tags: javascript, laravel, fetch, form-data, filelist

I'm trying to post multiple files from an input using fetch API but form data remains empty after appending

I looked at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14908250/5581565), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40826943/5581565), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50472925/5581565), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52996950/5581565) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13307822/5581565) and tried them all to no avail

Am using the Laravel framework for the backend, here's my Blade view file

```html
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<input class="form-control" type="file" id="pro-image" name="image[]" multiple onchange="submit()">

<script>
    function submit() {
        var ins = document.getElementById('pro-image').files.length;
        var fd = new FormData();
        for (var x = 0; x < ins; x++) {
            fd.append("pro-image[]", document.getElementById('pro-image').files[x]);
        }
        console.log(fd);
        fetch('/', {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                "X-CSRF-Token": document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content
            },
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: "same-origin",
            body: fd,
        });
    }
</script>
```

The console logs an empty form data object

[image]

And this is the code in the backend

```php
Route::post('/', function () {
    dd(request()->all());
});
```

In which I consequently get an empty array

[image]

Really can't tell why this isn't working! Any idea as to what am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your `Content-Type: application/json` header, or set it to `multipart/form-data` instead.

Comment: Setting it to `multipart/form-data` didn't help, removing it entirely fixes the issue, thanks

Comment: The console still logs an empty FormData, any idea why?

Comment: @Saly3301 You cannot inspect FormData by console logging it directly. You can either console log a specific value with FormData.get('key-name') or by using FormData.entries() as per this example:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries