# How to pass multiple files values ​through formdata ()

Tags: jquery

How do I pass multiple upload values ​​through formdata? I have the following form below:

```
<form action="#" class="form-horizontal"> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Titulo</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="titulo" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o titulo">
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Imagem</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="file" name="Arquivos[]" id="arquivos" class="form-control" multiple>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 0%">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success upload">Cadastrar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JQuery**

```
<script>
    $(document).on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //Receber os dados
        $form = $(this);                
        var formdata = new FormData($form[0]);
        //Criar a conexao com o servidor
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        //Progresso do Upload
        request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
            var percent = Math.round(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
            $form.find('.progress-bar').width(percent + '%').html(percent + '%');
        });
        //Upload completo limpar a barra de progresso
        request.addEventListener('load', function(e){
            $form.find('.progress-bar').addClass('progress-bar-success').html('upload completo...');
            //Atualizar a página após o upload completo
            setTimeout("window.open(self.location, '_self');", 1000);
        });
        //Arquivo responsável em fazer o upload da imagem
            request.open('post', 'processa.php');
            request.send(formdata);
            console.log(formdata);
    });
</script>
```

When I put it this way:

```
<input type="file" name="Arquivos" id="arquivos" class="form-control">
```

It works normally, but when I put:

```
<input type="file" name="Arquivos[]" id="arquivos" class="form-control" multiple>
```

It does not pass the values ​​to PHP. I've tried to put it this way:

```
formdata.append("Arquivos[]", document.getElementById('arquivos').files[0]);
```

It also didn't work!

The file processa.php looks like this:

```
$tmp_name = $_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'];
$name = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
for($c = 0; $c < count($tmp_name); $c++){
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, 'documento/'. $name);
}
```

But I think the problem is in Jquery, because as I said earlier, when I send without being multiple, it works correctly. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uploading multiple files using formData()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989442/uploading-multiple-files-using-formdata)

Comment: Try to echo $c in your php code and console.log(formdata) in jquery to see what is being passed when you try uploading

Answer (score 0):

When you have `[]` in the input name, `$_FILES['arquivo']['xxx']` become arrays. You knew this because you used `count($tmp_name)`, but then you forgot to index the variables.

```
for($c = 0; $c < count($tmp_name); $c++){
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name[$c], 'documento/'. $name[$c]);
}
```

Comment: Hello, Barmar. I did it that way, but it didn't work.

Comment: Hello, Drew. I saw the post, but I'm a layman in Jquery and I couldn't implement it in my code, because it has a progress bar.

Comment: Hello, Temidayo Dtuzzy Omotayo. Return: 
´(index):70 
FormData {}
__proto__: FormData
append: ƒ append()
delete: ƒ delete()
entries: ƒ entries()
forEach: ƒ forEach()
get: ƒ ()
getAll: ƒ getAll()
has: ƒ has()
keys: ƒ keys()
set: ƒ ()
values: ƒ values()
constructor: ƒ FormData()
Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ entries()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "FormData"
__proto__: Object´

Comment: `$_FILES['arquivos']` should be `$_FILES['Arquivos']`.

Comment: Use the Network tab of DevTools to confirm what's being submitted by AJAX.

Comment: `console.log(formdata)` isn't useful, it doesn't show the details.

Comment: You're right. It was my lack of attention ($_FILES['Arquivos']). Thank you very much Barmar. Greetings from Brazil.