# FastAPI - Uploading multiple files using Axios raises Bad Request error

Tags: javascript, python, file-upload, axios, fastapi

Client code:

```html
!<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>

<form id="uploadForm" role="form" method="post" enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" multiple>
    <input type=button value=Upload onclick="uploadFile()">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function uploadFile() {
   var formData = new FormData();
    var imagefile = document.querySelector('#file');
    formData.append("images", imagefile.files);
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload', formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    })
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Server code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, FastAPI
from typing import Optional, List
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse, HTMLResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

...

def save_file(filename, data):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(data)
        print('file saved')

@app.post("/upload")
async def upload(files: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
    print(files)
    for file in files:
        contents = await file.read()
        save_file(file.filename, contents)
        print('file received')

    return {"Uploaded Filenames": [file.filename for file in files]}
```

I get the following error:

```
 ←[32mINFO←[0m:     127.0.0.1:10406 - "←[1mPOST /upload HTTP/1.1←[0m" ←[31m400 Bad Request←[0m
```

I have tried to upload a single file via form action and all works fine, but I need to upload two files.

Comment: You're using `images` as the form key in JS, but `files` in your FastAPI definition. Does the 400 error have a body with more details? Does it work properly with a regular form and `<input type="file" name="images (or files)" multiple>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, when uploading files or form data, one should use the same form key defined in their endpoint/route. In your case, that is `files`. Hence, on client side you should use that key instead of `images`.

Second, the way to upload multiple files is to loop through the array of files (i.e., `imagefile.files` in your code) and add each file to the `FormData` object.

Third, the error seems to occur due to some bug/changes in the `0.27.1` version of Axios. Here is a recent [related issue on GitHub](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4648). Using the latest version, i.e., `0.27.2`, from cdnjs [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/axios/0.27.2) resolves the issue.

Alternatively, you could use [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71891621/17865804) (you can add the list of files in the same way as shown in the Axios example below). In Fetch API, when uploading files to the server, you **should not** explicitly set the `Content-Type` header on the request, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71711008/17865804).

### Working Example (using Axios)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Upload Files</title>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.27.2/axios.min.js"></script>   
   </head>
   <body>
      <input type="file" id="fileInput" multiple><br>
      <input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="uploadFile()">
      <script type="text/javascript">
         function uploadFile() {
             var fileInput = document.querySelector('#fileInput'); 
         
             if (fileInput.files[0]) {
                var formData = new FormData();
                for (const file of fileInput.files)
                    formData.append('files', file);

                 axios({
                         method: 'post',
                         url: '/upload',
                         data: formData,
                         headers: {
                             'Accept': 'application/json',
                             'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                         }
                     })
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error(error);
                    });
             }
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Axios v 0.27.2 you can [do this easily](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#-automatic-serialization):

```js
axios
    .postForm("https://httpbin.org/post", document.querySelector("#fileInput").files)
```

All the files will be submitted with `files[]` key.

More verbose example:

```js
    axios.postForm("https://httpbin.org/post", {
      "myField": "foo"
      "myJson{}": {x:1, y: 'bar'}, 
      "files[]": document.querySelector("#fileInput").files
    })
```