# How to upload a file from React front end to FastAPI?

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, axios, multipartform-data, fastapi

as the title says, I'm trying to upload a file from React front end to FastAPI. The code I used is below:

```
//this is backend FastAPI   ================== 
@app.post("/uploadfile")
async def create_upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    return {"filename": file.filename}

//frontend ===================================
const [file, uploadFile] = useState(null)

//when upload button clicked
function handleSubmit(){
    console.log(file[0].name)
    const formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append(
      "file",
      file[0],
    )
    axios.post("/uploadfile", {
      file:formdata}, {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      })
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response); //"dear user, please check etc..."
          });
      
  }

// this is when file has been selected
  function handleChange(e){
    uploadFile(e.target.files); //store uploaded file in "file" variable with useState
  }
```

It returns a 422 (Unprocessable Entity). The message detail from axios is:

[image]

I am not quite familiar with the rules and format needed behind file uploading. Could someone clear my confusion?

Comment: Related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72029319/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70689003/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74507628/17865804)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update from OP**:
I have managed to solve the problem by replacing the axios part with

```
const headers={'Content-Type': file[0].type}
await axios.post("/uploadfile",formdata,headers)
    .then()//etc
```

if anyone want to add more information on why that works please feel free to do so - since I'm not quite sure either.

Comment: This was helpful for me. I think the key is ensuring that the key to the form data matches the `UploadFIle` parameter for you FastAPI endpoint. In this case the key is `file`. 

In the react code you have:

    formdata.append(
      "file",
      file[0],
    )

And in the Python code you have:
```
    async def create_upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
```

Answer (score 0):

This was helpful for me finding a bug in my code. I suspect your problem was nesting the `formData` inside another object in your first attempt: `axios.post("/uploadfile", {file:formdata} ...` should be `axios.post("/uploadfile", formdata ...`.

For me, the trick was ensuring that the key to the `formData.append` exactly matches the name of the `UploadFile` parameter for my FastAPI endpoint.

In this example the name is `file123`.

In the React code you have:

```
formdata.append("file123", file[0])
axios.post("/uploadfile", formdata ...etc...
```

And in the Python code you have:

```
async def create_upload_file(file123: UploadFile = File(...)): ...etc...
```