# FastAPI returns "Error 422: Unprocessable entity" when I send multipart form data with JavaScript Fetch API

Tags: javascript, python, fetch, fetch-api, fastapi

I have some issue with using Fetch API JavaScript method when sending some simple `formData` like so:

```
function register() {
  var formData = new FormData();
  var textInputName = document.getElementById('textInputName');
  var sexButtonActive = document.querySelector('#buttonsMW > .btn.active');
  var imagesInput = document.getElementById('imagesInput');

  formData.append('name', textInputName.value);
  if (sexButtonActive != null){
    formData.append('sex', sexButtonActive.html())
  } else {
    formData.append('sex', "");
  }
  formData.append('images', imagesInput.files[0]);

  fetch('/user/register', {
    method: 'POST',
    data: formData,
  })
  .then(response => response.json());
}
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", register);
```

And on the server side (FastAPI):

```
@app.post("/user/register", status_code=201)
def register_user(name: str = Form(...), sex: str = Form(...), images: List[UploadFile] = Form(...)):
try:
    print(name)
    print(sex)
    print(images)
    return "OK"
except Exception as err:
    print(err)
    print(traceback.format_exc())
    return "Error"
```

After clicking on the submit button I get `Error 422: Unprocessable entity`. So, if I'm trying to add header `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`, it also doesn't help cause I get another `Error 400: Bad Request`. I want to understand what I am doing wrong, and how to process `formData` without such errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `422` error response body will contain an error message about which field(s) is missing or doesn’t match the expected format. Since you haven't provided that (please do so), my guess is that the error is triggered due to how you defined the `images` parameter in your endpoint. Since `images` is expected to be a `List` of `File`(s), you should instead define it using the `File` type instead of `Form`. For example:

```py
images: List[UploadFile] = File(...)
                           ^^^^
```

When using `UploadFile`, [you don't have to use `File()` in the default value of the parameter](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#file-parameters-with-uploadfile), meaning that the below should work as well:

```py
images: List[UploadFile]
```

Hence, the FastAPI endpoint should look similar to this:

```py
@app.post("/user/register")
async def register_user(name: str = Form(...), images: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
    pass
```

In the frontend, make sure to use the `body` (not `data`) parameter in the [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) function to pass the [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) object (see [example in MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_multiple_files)). For instance:

```js
var nameInput = document.getElementById('nameInput'); 
var imagesInput = document.getElementById('imagesInput');

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('name', nameInput.value);
for (const file of imagesInput.files)
    formData.append('images', file);

fetch('/user/register', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
   })
   .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
   })
   .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
   });
```

Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73264904/17865804), which provide working examples on how to upload multiple `files` and `form` data to a FastAPI backend, using Fetch API in the frontend.

As for manually specifying the `Content-Type` when sending `multipart/form-data`, you **don't** have to (and **shouldn't**) do that, but rather let the browser set the `Content-Type`—please take a look at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71711008/17865804) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, after reading your proof links I found the right solution (wrote below).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was having a similar problem and removed the header on my request where I manually added the Content-Type and it solved my 422 error (despite adding the same Content-Type header).

Answer (score 0):

So, I found that I has error in this part of code:

```
formData.append('images', imagesInput.files[0]);
```

Right way to upload multiple files is:

```
for (const image of imagesInput.files) {
    formData.append('images', image);
}
```

Also, we should use **File** in FastAPI method arguments `images: List[UploadFile] = File(...)` (instead of *Form*) and change *data* to *body* in JS method. It's not an error, cause after method called, we get right type of data, for example:

```
Name: Bob
Sex: Man
Images: [<starlette.datastructures.UploadFile object at 0x7fe07abf04f0>]
```