# Unprocessable Entity when uploading from Angular to Fast API

Tags: javascript, python, angular, http, fastapi

I am trying to send formData with an image from angular to fast API but am unable to process further because of the following error.

```
loc:(2)['body', 'file']
msg: "field required"
type: "value_error.missing"
```

This is how my code looks like
FastApi:

```
@app.post('/register')
async def register_user(user: UserData = Depends(), image: UploadFile = File(...)):
    ...
```

Angular:

```
registerUser(query: any,image:any) {
    
    const formData:FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', image,image.name);
    for (const key in query) {
        const element = query[key];
        formData.append(key, element);
    }
  
    return this.httpClient.post<any>(`${environment.apiBaseUrl}/register`, formData).pipe(map(res => {
      return res;
    }));
  }
```

but still, I am getting `422 (Unprocessable Entity)`

Comment: See related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70689003/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73264904/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72029319/17865804).

Comment: actually I am able to get the output for fast api swagger but don't know how to query it from angular

Comment: The body of the 422 error will have information about what information you're missing.

Comment: But I have already added that missing part in formData which is image.

Comment: Can you please tell me what should be the change in the angular code according to the fast API implementation?