# How to send multiple images form react

Tags: reactjs

I am not able to send multipleimages to node server, I have sent single image but not multiple

```
  const {register,handleSubmit}=useForm() 

    const onSubmit = async(images) => {
        const imageArray= Object.keys(images).map(item =>{ 
            return images[item] 
        })        

         let formData = new FormData()

        imageArray.map((file, index) => {
            formData.append(`images`, file[index])
          })   
       await uploadMultipleImages(formData)
    }
    return (
        <>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <input type='file' multiple {...register('multipleImages')} />
                <button type='submit' >Upload multiple images</button>
            </form>
        </>
    )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uploading multiple files using formData()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989442/uploading-multiple-files-using-formdata)

Answer (score 0):

It's a possible duplicate of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989442/uploading-multiple-files-using-formdata).

According to this and according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append), you should add `[]` to your name if you want to append multiple files on the same name.

So just:

```
...
formData.append(`images[]`, file[index])
...
```